# Proving that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K_r(0)$, $r>0$ is connected

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

$\mathbb{R}^p \setminus K_r(0)$, $r>0$.

How can I show that $\mathbb{R}^p \setminus K_r(0)$ is connected, that is, it cannot be divided into two disjoint nonempty open sets? I tried assuming that it isn't connected and find a contradiction but I can't get any further.

$K_r(0)$ is the closed circle around $0$ with radius $r$.

I know that I can also show path connected instead.

Comment: Would you care to define $K_r (0)$?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what $K_r(0)$ is.  It would also be helpful to know exactly what you tried, rather than to get a vague description like "I tried assuming that it isn't connected and...couldn't get any further."

Comment: $K_r(0)$ is the closed circle around $0$ with radius $r$.

Comment: What about $n=1$?

Comment: So $n \ge 3$ and the circle is in the x,y plane?

Comment: Circle? did you mean closed ball?

Answer (score 0):

For $n>2$ the $n-1$-sphere $S^{n-1}$ is connected and the map
$$R^n\backslash K_r(0)\ \longrightarrow\ S^{n-1}:\ x\ \longmapsto\ \frac{x}{||x||},$$
is continuous and surjective.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easier to prove directly that your set is path-connected and then to deduce that it is connected.

In order to prove that it is path-connected, take two points $a$ and $b$ from your set. Also, take a vector $v$ with norm $1$ which is orthgonal to the line passing through $a$ and $b$. Finally, considear a polygonal path as follows:

- At first, it goes (in a straight line) from $a$ to $a+2rv$;
- then, it goes (in a straight line) from $a+2rv$ to $b+2rv$;
- finally, it goes (still in a straight line) from $b+2rv$ to $b$.